# ASP.NET Getting "Authentication Required" when I upload a file

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I'm creating a page to upload images to the root and this is the following code

```
 if (fileimage.HasFile)
        {
            string Extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileimage.FileName);
            if (Extension.ToLower() != ".gif" && Extension.ToLower() != ".png" && Extension.ToLower() != ".jpg" && Extension.ToLower() != ".jpeg")
            {
                //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "popup", "alert('Invalid image format ');", true);
            }
            else
            {
                int FileSize = fileimage.PostedFile.ContentLength;
                if (FileSize > 1048576)
                {

                    //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "popup", "alert('Maximum file size 1 mb ');", true);
                }
                else
                {

                    string pathName = "img/" + Path.GetFileName(fileimage.PostedFile.FileName);
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=drasatwebmarket.db.10125920.hostedresource.com; Initial Catalog=drasatwebmarket; User ID=Username; Password='Password';");
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into imageupload(imagepath) values ('" + pathName + "')", con);
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    fileimage.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/webmaketing/img/" + fileimage.FileName));
                    Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('Image Uploaded Succssfuly')</script>");

                }
            }
        }
        else
        {

            Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('Please Select Image To Uploade')</script>");
        }
```

When I try to upload an image it shows up a dialog requesting user name and a password as following.
[image]

Note: the IIS settings at the server is set to anonymous access
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like GoDaddy so please try this in your web.config:

```
<system.web>
 <trust level="Full" />
</system.web>
```

Also check this if that alone does not solve it.

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
        <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Another quick test is to set Everyone-Read under File Manager permissions.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It answered with:    Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Comment: I can't find the Everyone-Read at the file manager permissions.

Comment: Please see image that I added.

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort, so much appreciated, though I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: In your case, you also want to allow Write access because you are saving a file which is not A Read action.

Comment: It answered again with: Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level. This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Comment: I thought by giving these permissions to the main directory it will affect it's children by inheritance, but I was wrong, I had to give these permissions to the uploading directory itself. Thank you very much!